# How to check if row with particular id exists in datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable, row

I have two datatable, while adding rows in second datatable, I want to first check whether the id in the second datatable matches as in the first datatable, if not only then it should be added in the second datatable, else it should display a message.

Please note, I don't have any Primary Key defined on any column, so the rows could be repetitive.

Comment: How you are copying records between databases; your sample query plz, so that we could change it.

Comment: i have 2grids, i am filling grid1 from datatable and saving dt in session, and using ths session to fill dt2 for grid2

if (secondDT.Columns.Count == 0)
{
fisrtDT = Session["FirstGrid"] as DataTable;
secondDT = fisrtDT.Clone();
}
foreach (GridViewRow row in FunGrid.Rows)
{
CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("chkBox") as CheckBox;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
if (chk.Checked)
{
DataRow dr = secondDT.NewRow();
dr["ModuleId"] = row.Cells[1].Text;
dr["FriendlyName"] = row.Cells[2].Text;
secondDT.Rows.Add(dr);
}
chk.Checked = false;
}
GridView1.DataSource = secondDT;
GridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (datatable2.Select("columnname = " + datatable1.Rows[0]["columnname"]).Length > 0)
{
     // row exist in table2
}
else {
    // does not exist in table2
}
```

For more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

Comment: i could not find anything like DataTable.Rows.Select, there is DataTable.Select() instead.

Can you please tell what you were talking about DataTable.Rows.Select or DataTable.Select

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Abbas, Oops I had a typo error; which I have corrected, have a look now.